# OnePlus one is charging but is recognized in device manager only when in debug mode

Tags: usb, data-transfer, android-device-manager

my oneplus one device (version 4.4.2) is not recognized anymore by the computer (OS WIN8) in the device manager, only when in developer mode - in usb-debug, does it show on the device manager (and even then it is not recognized as a storage device), I have installed the drivers successfully, but the moment the developer mode is turned off it was not recognized again.

Now, I haven't dropped the device and it is protected with a cover, what leads me to believe it may be a software issue.

I have tried already to format the cache partition, and it did not help.

Please help...

Comment: You say 4.4.2... Please update it to te latest  firmware.

Comment: You say it's not recognised any more: has it previously worked? What has changed since it worked?

Answer (score -2):

Are you using the red/white cable that came with the device? Most standard USB cables are not capable of file transfer, and so will not be recognized with Windows.

Comment: This doesn't make any sense.  There are not special data USB cakes.